# Irregular repetitions in table using JavaScript and Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to iterate over some data like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(k,val) in items">
        <td>{{k}} {{val.style}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(k2, item) in val.items">{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ingredients}}</td> <-- (a)
        <td>{{item.moreInfo}}</td> <-- (b)
    </tr>
</table>
```

(a) and (b) [and c, d, e...] would also use the object "item in val.items",
but {{item.ingredients}} is not a valid expression there, because it is out of the `<td>` with the object that I want to use to create more columns.

Example of what it would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/yj7xopgy/

Is there any way to do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points).

```
<td ng-repeat-start="(k2, item) in val.items">{{item.title}}</td>
<td>{{item.ingredients}}</td> 
<td ng-repeat-end>{{item.moreInfo}}</td>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yj7xopgy/1/)

Comment: You're my hero! I've been fighting with this forever. Thanks!